# Site tour page talks about unicorns and daisies instead of OSS

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tour

Why is the sample question in the site tour page about unicorns and daisies? Everywhere else uses a sample question from their site (to my knowledge).

[image: Tour page question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of the system.

There is an algorithm that determines which questions can be displayed in the tour page. I can't remember exactly what the requirements are, but in general terms it's looking for a short question with no fancy formatting.

Mods can change which question is displayed there, but only from those questions that this algorithm returns. Last time I checked, there weren't any eligible questions - and, having checked again just now, there still aren't any.

Comment: Well that is crummy....

Comment: Exactly that, we can't change it. It would be nice though to know which metrics have to be fulfilled so a question qualifies. Does anybody know that?

Comment: @Mnementh I expect there's a post on MSE somewhere that details it, though I can't find it.